# Copiar recursivamente recursos de Assets a Memoria interna en Android?

Tags: java, android

Tengo varios recursos en la carpeta `src/assets/` necesito copiar tal cual como se encuentran en otra ubicación, que sea accesible para el usuario, memoria interna `documents` o a la `sdcard`.

Teniendo en cuenta recursividad, si dentro del origen hay un directorio también copie los recursos del directorio.

Sería interesante, que Si en el destino ya se encuentran, que con un paramtro se puede decidir si sobrescribir o no.

Comment: He econtrado lo siguiente http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447477/android-how-to-copy-files-from-assets-folder-to-sdcard seria modificar un poco ese ejemplo para que acepte recursividad y detecte si se debe sobrescribir o no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adaptando una respuesta de [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275765/android-how-to-detect-a-directory-in-the-assets-folder) de @DannyA

```
private void copyAssets(String path, String outPath) {
    AssetManager assetManager = this.getAssets();
    String assets[];
    try {
        assets = assetManager.list(path);
        if (assets.length == 0) {
            copyFile(path, outPath);
        } else {
            String fullPath = outPath + "/" + path;
            File dir = new File(fullPath);
            if (!dir.exists())
                if (!dir.mkdir()) Log.e(TAG, "No create external directory: " + dir );
            for (String asset : assets) {
                copyAssets(path + "/" + asset, outPath);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Log.e(TAG, "I/O Exception", ex);
    }
}

private void copyFile(String filename, String outPath) {
    AssetManager assetManager = this.getAssets();

    InputStream in;
    OutputStream out;
    try {
        in = assetManager.open(filename);
        String newFileName = outPath + "/" + filename;
        out = new FileOutputStream(newFileName);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        in.close();
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

**Prerequesitos**

En el directorio `src/main/assets` deberemos crear un carpeta `fold` y allí es donde poner los archivos.

**Su Uso**

```
File outDir =  new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString());
copyAssets("fold",outDir.toString());
```